# Is $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x^2\cos x$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Is $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x^2\cos x$ uniformly
>   continuous?

**My attempt:**

My intuition doesn't tell me anything on this one. I tried standard procedures: its derivative is not bounded, hence not Lipschitz.

I tried to find equivalent sequences with non equivalent image sequences, but I couldn't find any.

This made me believe that the function is uniformly continuous, but I don't know how to prove it.

I tried to do this by the definition but I don't know how to handle the expression

$$|x² \cos(x) - y² \cos(x)|$$ given that $|x-y| < \delta$ for an appropriate delta.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I didn't have time to check all the answers in detail, but I will check them in the future and then I'll mark the answer that helped me the most! Thanks for your concern though!

Comment: In fact, I was hoping someone provided two simple equivalent sequences whose image sequences are not equivalent.

Comment: Possibly useful for intuiuton: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540090/find-a-function-that-is-continuous-on-0-1-but-not-uniformly-continuous-on-t/2540103#2540103

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*An explicit counterexample:*

Consider the sequence $(x_n)_n$ defined by $x_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} 2\pi n$. Assuming uniform continuity, we have, for $\varepsilon = 1$, some small $\delta>0$ (wlog $\delta < 2\pi$) such that in particular
$$
\lvert f(x_n+\delta) - f_n(x_n+\delta) \rvert \leq 1
$$
for all $n\geq 0$. However,
$$
f(x_n) = x_n^2 \cos(x_n) = x_n^2
$$
but
$$\begin{align}
 f(x_n+\delta) &= (x_n+\delta)^2\cos(x_n+\delta)
= (x_n+\delta)^2\cos(2\pi n+\delta)
= (x_n+\delta)^2\cos(\delta)
\\&= x_n^2\cos(\delta)+(2\delta x_n + \delta^2)\cos(\delta)
= x_n^2\cos(\delta) + o(x_n^2)
\end{align}$$
so that
$$\lvert f(x_n+\delta)-f(x_n)\rvert = (1-\cos(\delta))x_n^2 + o(x_n^2) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty
$$
contradicting the assumption.

Comment: This is more convincing answer (at least for beginners) +1

Answer (score 1):

No,
because $x^2$
has an unbounded derivative
and
there are arbitrarily large values
of $x$
where
$\cos(x)$
has its derivative
 bounded away from zero.

Comment: “cos has arbitrarily large values” ?! What do you mean?

Comment: @Lierre *"There are arbitrary large values where the derivative [of $\cos$] is bounded away from zero."*

Comment: Thanks - I did not say exactly what I wanted to. I've made a change which I hope makes it clearer.